# In Torch / Lua, what is the differece between loading a saved model and using Xavier weight initialization method?

Tags: lua, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I've been working with Torch and Lua on an artificial neural network project.

I sometimes used the commands `torch.save()` and `torch.load()` to save a trained model to a file and to load it into my scripts.

Recently, I've been studying the so called Xavier weight initialization method [originally developed by Xavier Glorot](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) in 2010.

I found an implementation of this weight initialization method in the [torch-toolbox package](https://github.com/e-lab/torch-toolbox/tree/master/Weight-init). The example contains this code:

```
-- design model 
require('nn') 
model = nn.Sequential() 
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(3,4,5,5))

-- reset weights 
method = 'xavier' 
model_new = require('weight-init')(model, method)
```

I ran this example in the Torch console and tried to analyze the content of the objects, such as model and model_new. I cannot see immediate difference, so I'm wondering: **what is the difference between using this Xavier `weight-init` model weight initialization and the classical torch.load() command?**

Answer (score 1):

Citing the mentioned docs:

```
The weights and biases in the network model will be reset based on the method provided.
```

So, `weight-init` **resets** all the weights in the network to some value (in case of Xavier method to `math.sqrt(2/(fan_in + fan_out)` (see [here](https://github.com/e-lab/torch-toolbox/blob/master/Weight-init/weight-init.lua#L19))).

On the other hand `torch.load()` reads the weights saved from a pre-trained file (that was saved with `torch.save()`). So, unless your weights didn't change at all during the training, if you do:

`weight-init() -> train -> torch.save() -> torch.load()`

you should see other results than with just weight-init().